# iOS AutoLayout growing row

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm a bit new to auto layout and got to a point where I'm stuck now. I searched the WWDC videos today because I remember an example but couldn't find it...

In it simples form the layout should be like this:

```
@"|[label]-[value1]-[value2]-[hideDetailsButton]|"
@"V:|[label]|"
```

But it should be possible to have multiple values, where the label and hideDetailsButton stay top aligned and the values grow into multiple rows. Like this:

```
@"|[label]-[value1]-[value2]-[hideDetailsButton]|"
@"|[value3]-[value4]-[value5]"
@"V:|[label]-[value3]|"
```

What constraints to I need for the value labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you watch WWDC 2012 [Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228), they walk you through this dynamic building of subviews and/or constraints in `layoutSubviews` (about 45 minutes into the video). That focuses on adding views that fit, but you can use it in your scenario, too.

The idea is that you have a `UIView` subclass for your container view with all of these labels and then override `layoutSubviews` to configure the constraints appropriately. It's a little hairy, but it works:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // add any labels for my `toRecipients` (and add to my dictionary that keeps
    // track of which `UILabel` is for which `toRecipient`)

    for (NSString *toRecipient in self.toRecipients)
    {
        UILabel *label = self.toLabels[toRecipient];
        if (!label)
        {
            label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            label.text = toRecipient;
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [self addSubview:label];
            [self.toLabels setObject:label forKey:toRecipient];
        }
    }

    // remove any existing constraints on subviews (you could keep track of them and
    // modify them, but I find it just as easy as to start from scratch every time)

    NSMutableArray *constraintsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints)
    {
        if ([constraint.firstItem superview] == self || [constraint.secondItem superview] == self) {
            [constraintsToRemove addObject:constraint];
        }
    }
    [self removeConstraints:constraintsToRemove];

    // add initial constraints for that leading "To:" label, putting it in the upper left corner

    NSDictionary *views = @{@"to" : self.toLabel};
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[to]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[to]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // now let's iterate through the `toRecipients`, and for each one, try adding
    // the label, see where constraints put it (using the label's intrinsic size, too),
    // and if it was too wide, then remove those constraints and add new constraints
    // to put it on the next line

    UIView *previousView = self.toLabel;
    for (NSString *toRecipient in self.toRecipients)
    {
        UIView *nextView = self.toLabels[toRecipient];
        views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousView, nextView);
        NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[previousView]-[nextView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
        [self addConstraints:constraints];
        [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
        [super layoutSubviews];
        if (CGRectGetMaxX(nextView.frame) < CGRectGetMaxX(self.bounds))
        {
            // if there was room, let's also set the baseline to be the same as the previous item

            [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBaseline multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise, let's get rid of the constraints I just added and move this next item down to the next line

            [self removeConstraints:constraints];
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[nextView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousView]-[nextView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        }

        previousView = nextView;
    }

    // set the bottom constraint for the last recipient

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[nextView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

The key to the dynamic height is that last constraint. In making this `UIView` subclass resize itself based upon the constraints and intrinsic size of the labels inside it, the height of this view will be defined by the labels inside it. When I add this subclassed view to my main view, I define it's top, left, and right to be defined by the main view, but I leave the bottom constraint undefined, and thus the last constraint, above, will define the height. So, adding this subclass to my main view looks like:

```
RecipientsView *recipientsView = [[RecipientsView alloc] init];
recipientsView.toRecipients = @[@"rob@frankfurt.de", @"r@berlin.de", @"frank@dusseldorf.de", @"ernest@munich.de", @"mo@cologne.de", @"curly@stuttgart.de"];
recipientsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
recipientsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:recipientsView];
self.recipientsView = recipientsView;

// set the left, right, and top constraints to the main view, but I'll let the
// intrinsic size of the labels dictate the height of this UIView subclass, RecipientsView

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(recipientsView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[recipientsView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[recipientsView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Note, I set the background color to light gray, so you can see that the height was dynamically set on the basis of all of the labels and their constraints:

[image: screen snapshot]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, the past days I was just all over this code!